# Ember with jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am trying to use jquery file upload with ember.js. What i am hoping to achieve is there is a file input and when user browse the picture and hit the upload button, the jquery file upload will upload the file and return with the location of the uploaded file then.. i will collect other data from the rest of the form and post the information using ember data, which will include the the image url and rest of the form data.

I cannot make it work, but the same code works with plain html file with php backend.

Here i have included non functional code in jsbin which include my template and app.js code

http://jsbin.com/EtOzeKI/1/edit

Comment: What portion of the code doesn't work?  This is completely possible to do.

Comment: when i select the image and hit upload nothing happens

Comment: no error on the console nothing.. i am having hard time geting this things right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an upload button that I use in my application:  It builds up an input button, and auto uploads on change.

```
{{view App.UploadButton groupBinding="model"}}


App.UploadButton = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    attributeBindings: ['type'],
    type: 'file',
    originalText: 'Upload Finished Product',
    uploadingText: 'Busy Uploading...',

    newItemHandler: function (data) {
        var store = this.get('controller.store');

        store.push('item', data);
    },

    preUpload: function () {
        var me = this.$(),
            parent = me.closest('.fileupload-addbutton'),
            upload = this.get('uploadingText');

        parent.addClass('disabled');
        me.css('cursor', 'default');
        me.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },

    postUpload: function () {
        var me = this.$(),
            parent = me.closest('.fileupload-addbutton'),
            form = parent.closest('#fake_form_for_reset')[0],
            orig = this.get('originalText');

        parent.removeClass('disabled');
        me.css('cursor', 'pointer');
        me.removeAttr('disabled');
        form.reset();
    },

    change: function (e) {
        var self = this;
        var formData = new FormData();
        // This is just CSS
        this.preUpload();
        formData.append('group_id', this.get('group.id'));
        formData.append('file', this.$().get(0).files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/file_upload_handler/',
            type: 'POST',
            //Ajax events
            success: function (data) { self.postUpload(); self.newItemHandler(data); },
            error: function () { self.postUpload(); alert('Failure'); },
            // Form data
            data: formData,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: it says textSpan is undefined, what is the function of textspan

Comment: It's just the text span, I was changing the text of the span, feel free to remove it, I did above.

Comment: both the pre and post upload are just css, you can completely remove them and they are unrelated.

Comment: thank you so much.. i am now working on php part of its upload

Comment: can you tell me how can i pass the value of the file input to my controller's variable?? i suppose it is called 'file' right now.. how can i be able to get the value from controller as or similar to this.get('file')

Comment: this is where I grab the file for submitting, formData.append('file', this.$().get(0).files[0]);

Comment: thank you so much.. you are a real savior .. warm regards from Nepal.

Comment: How would I get the file's blob. Currently the "file" object has: 
'name: "file.jpg"
size: 532246
type: "image/jpeg".

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minimal component you can use:

```
// index.html
<script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>/script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

// components/file-upload.js
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['name', 'data-url', 'multiple'],
    tagName: "input",
    type: 'file',
    name: "file[]",

    "data-url": function(){
        return this.get("path");
    }.property("path"),

    multiple: true,

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().fileupload();
    }
});

// to use in your hbs template
{{file-upload path="pathToUploadTo"}}
```